# Can't seem to raise ad viewability

Tags: google-adsense, viewability

I'm trying to raise my Adsense viewability from a very low 30-35% but I don't seem to be having any luck.

There are three primary ad placements on the page. All are above the fold.

In mobile there is a footer ad placement which is always anchored to the bottom of the screen.

In-article ads are handled automatically by Auto Ads.

Nothing seems to work. My viewability seems stuck at 30-35%.

What steps should I be taking to diagnose this issue, other than trying new ad placement positions?